# Delete attempt of Kubernetes resource reports not found, even though it can be listed with "kubectl get"

Tags: kubectl, kubeflow-pipelines, kubernetes-custom-resources, kubeflow-katib

I am running Kubeflow pipeline on a single node Rancher K3S cluster. Katib is deployed to create training jobs (Kind: TFJob) along with experiments (a CRD).
I can list the experiment resources with `kubectl get experiments -n <namespace>`. However, when trying to delete using `kubectl delete experiment exp_name -n namespace` the API server returns NotFound.

kubectl version is 1.22.12
kubeflow 1.6

How can a(any) resource be deleted when it is listed by "kubectl get , but a direct kubectl delete says the resource cannot be found?
Hopefully there is a general answer applicable for any resource.

Example:

```
kc get experiments -n <namespace>

NAME        TYPE      STATUS   AGE
mnist-e2e   Running   True     21h

kc delete experiment mnist-e2e -n namespace
Error from server (NotFound): experiments.kubeflow.org "mnist-e2e" not found
```

I have tried these methods, but all involve the use of the resource name (`mnist-e2e`) and result in "NotFound".

- I tried patching the manifest to empty the finalizers list:

```
kubectl patch experiment mnist-e2e \
-n namespace \
-p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":[]}}' \
--type=merge
```

- I tried dumping a manifest of the "orphaned" resource and then deleting using that manifest:

```
kubectl get experiment mnist-e2e -n namespace -o yaml > exp.yaml
kubectl delete -f exp.yaml
```

- Delete attempts from the Kubeflow UI Experiments (AutoML) page fail.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry the formatting did not behave as expected. The example should be 
"kubectl get experiments -n namespace",
 resulting in "NAME        TYPE       STATUS   AGE"
 "mnist-e2e  Running True       21h"

"kubectl delete experiment mnist-e2e -n namespace"
, resulting in "Error from server (NotFound): experiments.kubeflow.org "mnist-e2e" not found

Comment: I assume every occurrence of `namespace` should more consistently be `<namespace>` reflecting that it's some arbitrary value.

Comment: DazWilkin, yes you are correct.